# Android ImageView in Eclipse - Problems with image location

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to insert some pixel art for my app as an ImageView, but it's very stubborn once I have it in. Specifically, it's centered and pretty much locked into a grid.

I would like to naturally place the sprite where I want to instead of having it snap to a grid. Any suggestions? Here it is:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/cloud1" />
```

EDIT: Full XML

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Enter Two Numbers"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editOp1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editOp2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/sun" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubtract"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDivide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CLR" />
</TableRow>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="RESULT"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0.00"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/grass" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/grass" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/grass" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cloud2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cloud1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Make the root as `RelativeLayout`. Go to Design tab & drag to where ever you want it to be.

Comment: No problem. I'll just add it as answers. So it will help for future users who searches this. You can accept it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

All you wanted to do is make the xml layout root as `RelativeLayout` & Go to Design tab, drag to where ever you want it to be.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey again Yuva...I've made it a Relative Layout and I'm able to put a few sprites on there as ImageView(s). 

HOWEVER, when I have more than 4 or 5 sprites (distinct ImageViews) in my RelativeLayout, they seem to get troublesome and don't move where I want them...think of magnets opposing each other - they become very difficult to position...any ideas for this problem?

Bottom line, I just want to put multiple sprites on the screen with the least amount of trouble.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Just posted the .xml layout code in the edit above.